# db2look cuts longs procedures

Tags: db2, dllexport

I use db2look to export my DDL.

But it cuts off long procedures.

I use the following command:

db2look -td @ -d DBNAME -z SCHEMANAME -e -c -o dump.sql

If I use, for example, Toad for DB2, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version is reported by the db2level command, you may be able to correct the problem in db2look by applying a Fix Pack to your DB2 installation. What level does db2level say you currently have?

TOAD for DB2 is reading the TEXT column directly from SYSCAT.ROUTINES, which you can also access from a simple program or from DB2's built-in EXPORT utility.

Comment: C:\>db2level
DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09070" with
level identifier "08010107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.441", "s090521", "NTX6497", and Fix Pack
"0".
Product is installed at "C:\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

Comment: If you're using Express-C, you can install DB2 9.7 Fix Pack 2 over your current installation. If you are licensing some other edition of DB2 9.7, you can apply Fix Pack 3, which contains more fixes than Fix Pack 2.